# How to open /var/mobile/Containers/... from swift 4 application?

Tags: ios, swift, file

I want to open a local file from my appliaction.
I don't want to open the file directly in my application, I just want to make the command to open the specific file I have the path for.

The path to the file looks like this

```
    /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../filename.pdf
```

Is is possible to open a path like this with an external application like the "Files" application? 
Thanks

Comment: No you won't be able to view that. What you need to do it to download the container for that app. In Xcode, Window->Devices and Simulators -> Select your app and device -> Select the settings icon on bottom -> Download container

Comment: The problem is that I want to open the file (pdf or csv) when I click on the notification sent by my application. I can see the files I have downloaded with the app in "Files", open them and do whatever I want with them. Why isn't it possible, even if I have the path to the file?